# Initialize C runtime by multiple threads?

Tags: windows, multithreading, mingw-w64, crt

I am using MinGW-w64 on Windows. I am trying to make sense what is happening inside the CRT startup functions. The program entry point is `mainCRTStartup()`. This function initializes buffer security cookie, and then jumps to `__tmainCRTStartup()`, which ultimately calls `main()`. Now inside the [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/master/tree/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c) of `__tmainCRTStartup()` there is a curious operation:

```
while((lock_free = InterlockedCompareExchangePointer ((volatile PVOID *) &__native_startup_lock, fiberid, 0)) != 0)
{
  if (lock_free == fiberid)
  {
    nested = TRUE;
    break;
  }
  Sleep(1000);
}
```

Here `fiberid` is set to the base address of the thread stack.

It seems that the code is preventing multiple threads or fibers initializing CRT simultaneously. But why would there be multiple threads running `__tmainCRTStartup()` ? Since all threads share the same address space, wouldn't it be sufficient to just initialize CRT once? Also difficult to understand is the if-block inside the loop. To trigger this condition the `__native_startup_lock` must be already set to `fiberid`, which implies that the thread in question has already exited the loop. I do not see what kind of feature MinGW is trying to support here.

**Update**:

OK. I found a copy of Visual Studio 2013, shipped with the annotated CRT source code. Here's the annotation:

```
/*
 * There is a possiblity that the module where this object is
 * linked into is a mixed module. In all the cases we gurantee that
 * native initialization will occur before managed initialization.
 * Also in anycase this code should never be called when some other
 * code is initializing native code, that's why we exit in that case.
 */
```

This may explain the `nested` condition in the loop, but still I do not see why multithreading is involved here.

Comment: This is a copy/paste of the Microsoft code, naughty.  Except that the MSFT code does not have the Sleep() call, a second is bit over the top.    And has a comment that describes why it is necessary, deals with the case of a mixed-mode assembly.  The kind you generate with a C++/CLI project.  The entrypoint can be managed but the native code must be initialized first.  Hmm, this was dropped in the CRT rewrite for VS2015, that does explain the static initialization order fiasco problems it suffers from.